# SSIS Dealing with dates and null dates?

Tags: date, csv, ssis

I am trying to load a CSV file using MS-SSIS 2012. The dates in the CSV are formatted as;

```
1900-12-12
1987-01-23
.. etc
```

I wrote this piece of code to convert the dates from string to date and then fix the null values (not every row always has a date)

```
(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING(ISNULL(Geboortedatum) ? "1900-01-01" : Geboortedatum,1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(ISNULL(Geboortedatum) ? "1900-01-01" : Geboortedatum,6,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(ISNULL(Geboortedatum) ? "1900-01-01" : Geboortedatum,9,2))
```

This fails.. My original was;

```
(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING(Geboortedatum,1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING( Geboortedatum,6,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(Geboortedatum,9,2))
```

Which worked fine until I got NULL values in my file. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the error please?

Comment: [Derived Column [40]] Error: An error occurred while attempting to perform a type cast.
[Derived Column [40]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Derived Column" failed because error code 0xC0049064 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[Datumformat]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. A bit less complex and a bit faster then your code :)

```
(DT_DATE) (ISNULL(Geboortedatum) ? "1900-01-01" : (SUBSTRING(Geboortedatum,1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING( Geboortedatum,6,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(Geboortedatum,9,2)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I get the same error. In my CSV file the dates are between quotes, eg; "2015-01-01" and when it's empty it shows as "". Could it be this is not considered a "true" null value?

Comment: try to remove the quotes in Text qualifier tag in Flat file connection manager edit, adding "

Answer (score 0):

This did the job.. it seems like it was not a true null value.

```
(DT_DATE)(TRIM(Geboortedatum) == "" ? "1900-01-01" : (SUBSTRING(Geboortedatum,1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(Geboortedatum,6,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(Geboortedatum,9,2)))
```